# Removing block from layout doesn't work

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, theme, xml

I want to remove the `register-link` from the header links, so I have wrote in the `default.xml` of the `Module_Customer` of my theme:

```
<referenceBlock element="register-link" remove="true"/>
```

The problem is the block is not removed and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use name instead of element in your xml

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
```